# How to create a dynamic object with an array inside so that it does not overwrite?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to create a dynamic object with an array inside so that it does not overwrite?

```
    let id;
    let obj = {};
    obj[id] = []; // if I declare  here inside the function it is undefined

    function ex(event) {
       id = event.id;
       obj[id] = [];// if I declare obj[id]=[]  here its overwrite
       obj[id].push(event.data);
    }

    //what needs to be done to get global obj like this


     {
         31dsa: ['sdf32da', '3fsdffs'],
         1dfga: ['hfs32da'],
         ....
    }
```

Comment: hi please clarify what you need we are all here to help you , also add same data , or code you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate if the array exist.

```
 function ex(event) {
   id = event.id;
   if (!obj[id]){ // if undefined its falsy
      obj[id]= [];
   }
   obj[id].push(event.data);
}
```